# Maven compilation (java8 compatibility java6)

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, java-8, java-6

I have problem with my maven build because recently we have changed our java.

I launch maven build with java8 and I want my code to compile with java6. So for this I added this to my pom:

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.6</source>
            <target>1.6</target>
            <optimize>true</optimize>
            <compilerVersion>1.6</compilerVersion>   
            <compilerId>eclipse</compilerId>
            <executable>${JAVA_1_6_HOME}/bin/javac</executable>
            <verbose>true</verbose>
            <fork>true</fork>
            <debug>true</debug>
        </configuration>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
                <artifactId>plexus-compiler-eclipse</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
                <artifactId>plexus-compiler-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </plugin>
```

But when I launch maven build I have this error which only exists in java8 (Duplicate methods named spliterator with the parameters () and () are inherited from the types `List<T>` and `Collection<T>`).

Do you have any idea why my code seems to be compile with java8?

(part of logs)

```
(f) compilerId = eclipse
[DEBUG]   (f) compilerVersion = 1.6
[DEBUG]   (f) debug = true
[DEBUG]   (f) encoding = UTF-8
[DEBUG]   (f) executable = C:\Program Files\Java60\java\bin\javac
[DEBUG]   (f) failOnError = true
[DEBUG]   (f) forceJavacCompilerUse = false
[DEBUG]   (f) fork = true
```

Comment: Why both eclipse and javac?

Comment: Also, run as fast as possible away from Java 6.  Move to Java 8 if you can.

Comment: The best solution is to use [toolchains](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-toolchains.html) and use a real JDK 6 to compile and test your code with the correct JDK. Or you use JDK 8 to compile but use [animal-sniffer-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/animal-sniffer/animal-sniffer-maven-plugin/) to keep your code compatible with JDK 6.

Comment: what maven command you have executed to run this ? And also tell the maven version you are using

Comment: Sounds like you are asking Java 6 compilers to understand a JRE 8 library containing default methods. In other words: you are asking for trouble. Don't!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use compiler from java 8. Now you hardcoded `${JAVA_1_6_HOME}/bin/javac`. Use something like: `${JAVA_1_8_HOME}/bin/javac`

Comment: My code is not compatible with java8 because some class extends List. And I forget to precise I need to launch ear in java6